Gunicorn fails in Docker with CMD command
I have a Flask application that runs on Gunicorn, and I would like to dockerize my app. To achieve this, I have set up a Dockerfile where I want to start a Gunicorn server within my Docker image. The Gunicorn server should be started using the following CMD command.
WORKDIR /home/glue_user/workspace/flask_app/
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:443", "app_flask:application","--workers=5","--timeout=600", "--worker-tmp-dir=/dev/shm" ,"--certfile=gunicorn_local.crt", "--keyfile=gunicorn_local.key"] 

Unfortunatly it fails with the following error.
/home/glue_user/.local/bin/gunicorn: line 3: import: command not found
/home/glue_user/.local/bin/gunicorn: line 4: import: command not found
/home/glue_user/.local/bin/gunicorn: line 5: from: command not found
/home/glue_user/.local/bin/gunicorn: gunicorn: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('

The error originates from the Gunicorn start script, but I'm unsure about what is causing it. When I start the Docker container on a bash endpoint and manually start the Gunicorn server, everything works fine. This is the command i use for a manually start.
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash -v ~/.aws:/home/glue_user/.aws -e AWS_PROFILE=$AWS_PROFILE  -it my_docker_image

The image is based on amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01.
This is my Dockerfile
FROM amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01

# set current env
ENV FLASK_DEBUG 0
ENV PYTHONPATH /home/glue_user/workspace/flask_app

RUN mkdir /home/glue_user/workspace/flask_app
WORKDIR /home/glue_user/workspace/flask_app/
COPY requirements.txt /home/glue_user/workspace/flask_app/

## Install pip requirements
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /home/glue_user/workspace/flask_app/requirements.txt

COPY . /home/glue_user/workspace/flask_app/


# Docker container listen to port 
EXPOSE 443

# start gunicorn wsgi server, module:flask_instance
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:443", "app_flask:application","--workers=5","--timeout=600", "--worker-tmp-dir=/dev/shm" ,"--certfile=gunicorn_local.crt", "--keyfile=gunicorn_local.key"]


Can you show us the complete Dockerfile? Does your image have an ENTRYPOINT set? If so, what does that script look like?

@larsks
Added the Dockerfile to my original post.

The Docker Hub image page for that base image is a little sparse on details, but it does include an automatically-generated extract of a Dockerfile.  The very last line there is
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-l"]

This line is problematic.  Because the CMD is passed as arguments to the ENTRYPOINT, you get an effective command of bash -l gunicorn ..., and the Bourne shell interpreter tries to run a Python script.  That leads to the problems you see.  It also looks like the image tries to put a required setup script in /home/glue_user/.bashrc, which is tricky to use.
If you can use the plain Docker Hub python image as a base, it might work better.
You can also disable the base image's ENTRYPOINT like
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD ["gunicorn", ...]

If you really need the .bashrc file, you can either run your command via a shell
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:4443 ...
# Note, plain string as `CMD`, not JSON-array syntax

or write an entrypoint wrapper script that reads the init file and then runs the main container process.
#!/bin/bash
. $HOME/.bashrc
exec "$@"

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:443", ...]


Thank you all for your responses. In my case, I found that disabling the ENTRYPOINT of the base image and starting Gunicorn using the CMD command was the solution that worked for me. @David Maze, I have chosen to stick with the glue image because it provides a predefined configuration for PySpark. Despite having PySpark included in the PATH variable and being able to start PySpark from the command line within the running Docker container, I encountered failures when Gunicorn started my application due to missing PySpark modules. One problem has been solved, but another one has emerged.

I managed to resolve the problem with PySpark by using import findspark, as suggested in this link. However, I'm not entirely sure if it is considered a good practice to combine Gunicorn and PySpark within the same process. In my case, PySpark is utilized for querying data from AWS S3, while Gunicorn is responsible for hosting a Dash App to display the queried data.
